# apache http client upload file log request body

Tags: http, apache-httpclient-5.x

I use the following code to print the request body log, but when I upload the file, a large number of logs will be printed. What can I do to solve it.

code:

```
HttpEntity requestEntity = request.getEntity();
String body = EntityUtils.toString(requestEntity, "UTF-8");
if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(body)) {
    logBuilder.append("body: ").append(body);
}
```

log:

```
body: --18aa6b77bdc
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="upload_id"
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8

00ebd6507dcef9b08c957fe0496ba1e2
--18aa6b77bdc
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename=""
Content-Type: Content-Type: text/plain
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary

5ee8aa3208ed1ce65c
8d2757ef0d5221182b0c30d957de3ede
1bff31c1f7090d0d26c1662f2368a034
9738ce5df78146aaa9c784acbca11d63
8e4d93b7f3a5671c059d6424140b6777
18ab2db397056d05d85552b650479ca2
cce88c588b225d5a26546a7950ad008c
06da6dc9de4646bffee346936b29aa31
9d6222eb6e6a459fe3233dd86e8e8f2d
6c19c0785b5e0f87e620ceeefed8a7b2
8e549e08369f53827d55da81e3ba495b
c099732d439032c8623efac6a8804392
9741dcd7b3ac27b23908ae81ed962dcf
5533f47f1278dd4bfecd3b394755534e
9eacdd442f5c41be4d80e3b12fd95a12
2fc7f22d3b39844503abafef8ccf5f04
77820b22a8405a3e8282010e57232fa4
de48ed7e54f3bba92ccc335b5ae6f7bf
4d659613677bbcadbc1ec56cd3501672
63ec0a484027a2678e8b17ecea63438c
0650ea8f16e6230d6a95544a06afec84
efa89641f2448cc269237d9aebf6e67c
c6afc30bea7c0aec95c2a3ed54787194
0b501e09a3853753dd4c49e34f7a1513
703cbaed1960634e354ce4f0b6c3c598
19887a74d53a9df174abca14bc8af176
3c5c1cafdc3be215cde34b4fe9a4600b
......
```

Is there any way to not print the contents of the file and only print the normal form data parameters